# Flatten deep nested json in R

Tags: json, r, recursion, nested, flatten

I am trying to use R to convert a nested JSON file into a two dimensional dataframe.

My JSON file has a nested structure. But, the names and properties are the same across levels.

```
{"name":"A", "value":"1", "c":
  [{"name":"a1", "value":"11", "c":
    [{"name":"a11", "value":"111"}, 
    {"name":"a12", "value":"112"}]
  }, 
  {"name":"a2", "value":"12"}]
}
```

The desired dataset would look like this.  Although the exact column names can be different.

```
name    value   c__name c_value c_c_name    c_c_value
A       1       a1      11      a11         111
A       1       a1      11      a12         112
A       1       a2      12
```

The code I have so far flattens the data, but it only seems to work for the first level (see the screenshot of the output).

```
library(jsonlite)
json_file <- '    {"name":"A", "value":"1", "c":
      [{"name":"a1", "value":"11", "c":
[{"name":"a11", "value":"111"}, 
{"name":"a12", "value":"112"}]
}, 
{"name":"a2", "value":"12"}]
}'

data <- fromJSON(json_file, flatten = TRUE)
View(data)
```

[image]

I tried multiple packages, including jsonlite and RJSONIO, I spent the last 5 hours 5 hours debugging this and trying various online tutorial, but without success.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: have you looked at the `purrr` package? it does a great job w/making list extraction less painful.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, that is some ugly JSON; if you have a way of avoiding it, do so. Consequently, what follows is also pretty ugly—to the degree that I normally wouldn't post it, but I am doing so now in the hope that some of the approaches may be of use. If it offends your eyes, let me know and I'll delete it.

```
library(jsonlite)    # for fromJSON
library(reshape2)    # for melt
library(dplyr)       # for inner_join, select

jlist <- fromJSON(json_file)
jdf <- as.data.frame(jlist)
jdf$c.value <- as.numeric(jdf$c.value)          # fix type
jdf$L1 <- as.integer(factor(jdf$c.name))        # for use as a key with an artifact of melt later *urg, sorry*
ccdf <- melt(jdf$c.c)                           # get nested list into usable form
names(ccdf)[1:2] <- c('c.c.name', 'c.c.value')  # fix names so they won't cause problems with the join
df3 <- inner_join(jdf[, -5], ccdf)              # join, take out nested column
df3$c.c.value <- as.numeric(df3$c.c.value)      # fix type
df3 <- df3 %>% select(-L1, -c)                  # get rid of useless columns
```

which leaves you with

```
> df3
  name value c.name c.value c.c.name c.c.value
1    A     1     a1      11      a11       111
2    A     1     a1      11      a12       112
3    A     1     a2      12     <NA>        NA
```

with reasonably sensible types. The packages used are avoidable, if you like.

Is this scalable? Well, not really, without more of the same mess. If anybody else has a less nasty and more scalable approach for dealing with nasty JSON, please post it; I'd be as grateful as the OP.

Comment: Thanks alistaire for sharing!  I think I found a way to do this (see my answer). I am sure there is a more concise solution out there, but for now this seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out a way to do this.  It seems to work with larger trees. The idea is to unlist the JSON and use the names attribute of the unlisted elements.  In this example, if a node has one parent, the name attribute will start with "c.", if it has a parent and a "grandparent", it will list it as "c.c."...etc. So, the code below uses this structure to find the level of nesting and placing the node in the appropriate columns.  The rest of the code adds the attributes of the parent nodes and deletes extra rows generated.  I know it is not elegant, but I thought it might be useful for others.

```
library(stringr)
library(jsonlite)

json_file <- '    {"name":"A", "value":"1", "c":
                  [{"name":"a1", "value":"11", "c":
                  [{"name":"a11", "value":"111"}, 
                  {"name":"a12", "value":"112"}]
                  }, 
                  {"name":"a2", "value":"12"}]
                  }'

nestedjson <- fromJSON(json_file, simplifyVector = F) #read the json
nAttrPerNode <- 2 #number of attributes per node
strChild <- "c." #determines level of nesting

unnestedjson <- unlist(nestedjson) #convert JSON to unlist 
unnestednames <- attr(unnestedjson, "names") #get the names of the cells
depthTree <- (max(str_count(unnestednames, strChild)) + 1) * nAttrPerNode #maximum tree depth 
htTree <- length(unnestednames) / nAttrPerNode #maximum tree height (number of branches)

X <- array("", c(htTree, depthTree))
for (nodeht in 1:htTree){ #iterate through the branches and place the nodes based on the count of strChild in the name attribute
   nodeIndex <- nodeht * nAttrPerNode 
   nodedepth <- str_count(unnestednames[nodeIndex], strChild) + 1
   X[nodeht, nodedepth * nAttrPerNode - 1] <- unnestedjson[nodeIndex - 1]
   X[nodeht, nodedepth * nAttrPerNode] <- unnestedjson[nodeIndex]
}

for (nodeht in 2:htTree){ #repeat the parent node attributes for the children
  nodedepth <- 0
  repeat{
    nodedepth <- nodedepth + 1
    startcol <- nodedepth * nAttrPerNode - 1
    endcol <- startcol + nAttrPerNode - 1
    if (X[nodeht, startcol] == "" & nodedepth < depthTree/nAttrPerNode){
      X[nodeht, startcol:endcol] <- X[nodeht-1, startcol:endcol]
    } else {
      break()
    }
  }
}

deleteRows <- NULL #Finally delete the rows that only have the parent attributes for nodes that have children
strBranches <- apply(X, 1, paste, collapse="")
for (nodeht in 1:(htTree-1)){
  branch2sub <- substr(strBranches[nodeht+1], 1, nchar(strBranches[nodeht]))
  if (strBranches[nodeht]==branch2sub){
    deleteRows <- c(deleteRows, nodeht)
  }
}
deleteRows
X <- X[-deleteRows,]
```